# Different result from rails and irb for YoutubeDL.get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-dl

I'm using gem 'youtube-dl.rb'.

From irb, I can get full result, about video, but at the rails 4.2 - I can't.

irb

```
require 'youtube-dl.rb'     
a = YoutubeDL.get "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dsGWM5XGdg", {skip_download: true}
```

Result https://pastebin.com/9SLbs5GF (With a lot of data).

rails c

```
require 'youtube-dl.rb'     
a = YoutubeDL.get "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dsGWM5XGdg", {skip_download: true}
```

Result from rails console have only this:

```
 => #<YoutubeDL::Video:0x007fbc29de1498 @url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dsGWM5XGdg", @options=#<YoutubeDL::Options:0x007fbc29de1448 @store={:skip_download=>true}>, @download_options=#<YoutubeDL::Options:0x007fbc29de1150 @store={:color=>false, :progress=>false, :skip_download=>true}>, @last_download_output="[youtube] 5dsGWM5XGdg: Downloading webpage\n[youtube] 5dsGWM5XGdg: Downloading video info webpage\n[youtube] 5dsGWM5XGdg: Extracting video information\n[youtube] 5dsGWM5XGdg: Downloading MPD manifest\n">
```

How I Can get the same result for RoR?

Comment: I just installed the gem and ran your code in both a new IRB shell and a Rails console, and got identical results (aside from unique strings). Both matched the shorter Rails console version in your question. Could there be some sort of config option you have set in your IRB shell that's resulting in additional data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check youtube-dl.rb version inside your rails app and inside your machine enviro

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's true. I'm removed youtube-dl lib from laptop and installed youtube-dl.rb from my fork with updated library. Now it's the same.